# Removing an attribute - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this very simple select. I want to have only an option when I open the page.

```
<select class="custom-select form-control" id="coreBankingProject" name="coreBankingProject" readonly="true">
    <option>{{settings.coreBankingProject}}</option>
</select>
```

But then I click a button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline" (click)="getGitlabProjects()"><span class="fa fa-download"></span> Get projects</button>
```

I run a function that get's a list of projects.

```
getGitlabProjects() {
  this.gitlabService.getProjects(this.gitlabUrl, this.gitlabToken).subscribe(projects => {
    this.projects = projects;
  })
}
```

**How do I now clean that select option and insert the projects there? I want to show the project names `project.name` and I also need to remove the readonly attribute.**

edit: my current code only shows the options in the last select. I have 4 selects.

```
 getGitlabProjects() {
this.gitlabService.getProjects(this.gitlabUrl,this.gitlabToken).subscribe(projects => {
  this.projects = projects;
  this.btnGetProjectsClicked = true;
  console.log(projects);
  let coreBankingProjectSelect = document.getElementById("coreBankingProject");
  let customerUIProjectSelect = document.getElementById("customerUIProject");
  let adminUIProjectSelect = document.getElementById("adminUIProject");
  let clientUIProjectSelect = document.getElementById("clientUIProject");

  //remove previous options
  coreBankingProjectSelect.innerHTML = '';
  customerUIProjectSelect.innerHTML = '';
  adminUIProjectSelect.innerHTML = '';
  clientUIProjectSelect.innerHTML = '';

  for(let i=0;i<projects.length;i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = projects[i].name;
    option.value = projects[i].name;

    //append projects
    coreBankingProjectSelect.appendChild(option);
    customerUIProjectSelect.appendChild(option);
    adminUIProjectSelect.appendChild(option);
    clientUIProjectSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
  // remove readonly
  coreBankingProjectSelect.removeAttribute("readonly");
  customerUIProjectSelect.removeAttribute("readonly");
  adminUIProjectSelect.removeAttribute("readonly");
  clientUIProjectSelect.removeAttribute("readonly");


})
```

}

Comment: **please check my edit.**

Answer (score 0):

Insert options :

```
select = document.getElementById('coreBankingProject');
select.innerHTML = '';

for (index = 0; index < this.projects.length; ++index) {
   const p = this.projects[index];
   if (index === 0){
      opt.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
   }
   var opt = document.createElement('option');
   opt.value = p.name;
   opt.innerHTML = p.name;
   select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Remove readonly :

```
select.removeAttribute('readonly');
```

Comment: I'm only missing one thing. how do I select the first option?

Comment: `coreBankingProjectSelect.selectedIndex = 0;` doesn't exist

Comment: I added the selected option

Comment: This code doesn't work for multiple stuff. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Please up and mark as answer if this issue is closed

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone already got to the removeAttribute part of the answer, if you also wanted to remove the previous option from the select, you can simply add the following before the for loop that vbuzze suggested.

```
select.innerHTML = '';
```